# Using future object to return not the promise but the data

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
$scope.property = $http.get(url).then(function(res) { 
   return res.data;
});
```

Just like a $resource, which I can use:

```
$scope.MyProp = MyResource.query();
```

(as seen in https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11)

I'm not having success in my code, but I was successful in a jsfiddle that I created for tests. Later I found out that the problem is that angular 1.2+ doesn't support this technic.

You can find it out on http://jsfiddle.net/victorivens05/5jdsmk4s/ just by changing the framework from 1.1.1 to 1.2.1.

I want to know if there is a way to acomplish this behaviour in angular 1.2+.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you want to do wouldn't something like this work?

```
  var promise = $http.get(url);
  promise.then(function(res) {
    $scope.property = res.data;
  });
```

Comment: Yes, but im my case i want to return a value either from a http request, localstorage or even a var that I have. For me to use that I would have to create a promise, return it to the scope to use .then and resolve it. That is what i'm trying to avoid.